# JQuery use mouseover dynamically on an HTML list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm sorry if I didn't word the title the best way, but here's the problem I'm attempting to solve. I have an audio player that allows you to select songs from an list index. With that index I also have a description that pops up when you click on the song. I'm looking to transfer that into a hover so that whenever any song in the list is hovered, the description will appear and when you move the mouse away it will go away as well.

The JS -

```
function audioPlayer(){
        var descriptions = ["Sad Man's Tongue. . .Description to follow",
        "Breed. . .Description to follow",
        "Everything Zen. . .Description to follow",
        "Ain't It Funky Now Pt2. . .Description to follow",
        "Killing All The Joy. . .Description to follow",
        "OWS. . .Description to follow",
        "X1 Alpha. . .Description to follow",
        "Low. . .Description to follow",
        "Reconsider Baby. . .Description to follow",
        "4Lee. . .Description to follow",
        "Show Biz Kids. . .Description to follow"
    ];

        var currentSong = 0;
        $("#audioPlayer")[0].src = $("#playlist li a")[0];
        $("#playlist li a").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#audioPlayer")[0].src = this;
            $("#audioPlayer")[0].play();
            $("#playlist li").removeClass("current-song");
            currentSong = $(this).parent().index();
            $(this).parent().addClass("current-song");
            let currentDescription = descriptions[currentSong]
            $('#song-info').css('display', 'inline');
            $('#song-info').text(currentDescription);
         });

    $("#audioPlayer")[0].addEventListener("ended", function(){
  $("#playlist li").removeClass("current-song");
        $('#song-info').css('display', 'inline');
        $('#song-info').text("Time for the next song ...turn it up LOUDER");
        $("#audioPlayer")[0].src = $("#playlist li a")[currentSong].href;
        $("#audioPlayer")[0].play;
    });

    $("#audioPlayer")[0].addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
        let hoverDescription = description[$(this).index()];
        document.getElementById("song-hover-info").style.zIndex = "11";
        $('#song-hover-info').css('display', 'inline');
        $('#song-hover-info').text(hoverDescription);
    });
    $("#audioPlayer")[0].addEventListener("mouseleave", function(){
        document.getElementById("song-hover-info").style.zIndex = "9";
    });

    }// JavaScript Document
```

The CSS -

```
.current-song{
            color:aqua;
}
    .footer{
        position: fixed;
        text-align: center;
        bottom: 0px;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .blacktextbg{
        background-color: #000000;
    }
    #playlist{
        font-size: 24;
    }
    .fader{
        position: absolute;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: -1;
        background-size: 100% 100%;
        background-repeat : no-repeat;
    }
    #song-info{
        padding: 10px;
        color: black;
        background-color: white;
        border: black 2px;
        width: 25%;
        z-index: 10;

    }
    #song-hover-info{
        padding: 10px;
        color: black;
        background-color: white;
        border: black 2px;
        width: 25%;
        z-index: 9;
    }
```

Relevant HTML

```
<audio src="" controls id="audioPlayer">
    Sorry, your browser doesn't support html5!
</audio>
<ul id="playlist">
      <li><a href="sounds/Sad%20Mans%20Tongue.mp3"><span class="blacktextbg">Sad Man's Tongue</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="sounds/breed.mp3"><span class="blacktextbg">Breed</span></a></li>
    <!--<li><a href="sounds/creep.mp3">Creep</a></li>-->
    <li><a href="sounds/Everything%20Zen.mp3"><span class="blacktextbg">Everything Zen</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="sounds/Ain't%20It%20Funky%20Now%20Pt%202.mp3"><span class="blacktextbg">Ain't It Funky Now Pt 2</span></a></li>
    <!--<li><a href="sounds/once.mp3">Once</a></li>-->
    <li><a href="sounds/killing all the joy.mp3"><span class="blacktextbg">Killing All The Joy</span></a></li>
    <!--<li><a href="sounds/torn.mp3">Torn</a></li>
    <li><a href="sounds/aftermidnight.mp3">After Midnight</a></li>-->
    <li><a href="sounds/X1BetaOWS.mp3"><span class="blacktextbg">OWS</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="sounds/X1 Alpha.mp3"><span class="blacktextbg">X1 Alpha</span></a></li>
    <!--<li><a href="sounds/undome.mp3">Undo Me</a></li>-->
    <li><a href="sounds/Low%20.mp3"><span class="blacktextbg">Low</span></a></li>
    <!--<li><a href="sounds/Cumbersome.mp3">Cumbersome</a></li>
    <li><a href="sounds/Thru%20Your%20Window%20.mp3">Thru Your Window</a></li>-->
    <li><a href="sounds/Reconsider%20Baby.mp3"><span class="blacktextbg">Reconsider Baby</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="sounds/4lee.mp3"><span class="blacktextbg">4LEE</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="sounds/show%20biz%20kids.mp3"><span class="blacktextbg">Show Biz Kids</span></a></li>
    <!--<li><a href="sounds/show%20biz%20guitar.mp3">Show Biz Guitar</a></li>
    <li><a href="sounds/Voodoo%20Child.mp3">Voodoo Child</a></li>
    <li><a href="sounds/saveme.mp3">Save Me</a></li>-->
</ul>
<script src="audioPlayer.js"></script>
<script>
    audioPlayer();
</script>
<div id="song-info">
    Select a song above and turn it up LOUD
</div>
<div id="song-hover-info">
</div>
```

The array descriptions holds the individual song descriptions.

The z-index is because I don't want to get rid of song-info, it serves a purpose for after a song has ended. I want the hover information to appear when there is a hover so that was the first solution that came to mind.

Comment: Please include HTML, CSS, and any other code that affect it..

Answer (score 0):

If your UL LI html syntax is the area of your code that users will be hovering on, the code below should give you the ability to detect when someone is hovering over one of your LI elements.

```
$('#playlist').on({ 
    mouseenter: function() { 
        alert('mouseenter - hovered'); 
    }, 
    mouseleave: function() {
        alert('mouseleave - no hover');
    }
}, 'li');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
    var descriptions = ["Sad Man's Tongue. . .test1",
    "Breed. . .test2",
    "Everything Zen. . .test3",
    "Ain't It Funky Now Pt2. . .test4",
    "Killing All The Joy. . .test5",
    "OWS. . .test6",
    "X1 Alpha. . .test7",
    "Low. . .test8",
    "Reconsider Baby. . .test9",
    "4Lee. . .test10",
    "Show Biz Kids. . .test11"]

  $( "li" ).hover(function() {                               
      var i=0;
      while (i<descriptions.length)
      {
        if($(this).text() == descriptions[i].split(". . .")[0].toString())
        {
            document.getElementById("song-hover-info").innerHTML = descriptions[i].split(". . .")[1]; 
        }
        i+=1;
      }

        });
```